# Database Design: OK? not to use foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

Is it ok if i dont use a foreign key, when i could use it, i just dont use it?

For example, my COUNTRY_STATE table should have Country.Id as the foreign key, but i didn't do that instead have CountryCode. I get the states for each country by CountryCode.

```
COUNTRY
-Id (PK)
-Code
-Name
```

---

```
COUNTRY_STATE
-Id (PK)
-Code
-Name
-CountryCode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key does not necessarily need to reference a primary key. It can also reference a unique constraint.

So if you want to keep the country_code in the country_state table, you can do that and still have a foreign key that ensure that only valid country codes are used:

```
ALTER TABLE country 
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_code UNIQUE (code);

ALTER TABLE country_state 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_state_country 
    FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES country (code);
```

Comment: You could also drop the surrogate primary key from the Country table and make the Code the primary key.  With either of these approaches, you're assuming the Code will rarely change...

Answer (score 2):

It is not OK, you are violating the [Referencial Integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) property

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that guarantees that the country code will be unique, so you have introduced a possible one-to-many relationship there. That means that a country state could have more than one country...which is undesirable.

Comment: I have a unique index on CountryCode, so it will always be unique. It can in fact become the primary key.

Comment: Then you should be fine...there is no rule saying that it has to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key that does not use nocheck will allow the query optimizer to simplify the plan. This will allow fewer reads which will improve query performance. This will have a dramatic effect on performance, when your row count gets high.